# Decoding object with multiple constuctors with separated tags

Tags: json, haskell, generics, aeson

I have data in form of pairs of two strings, where first is the key identifying shape of the JSON delivered as the second one.

```
fooooo
{"a": 123}

barrrr
{"a": 123, "b": 123}

fooooo
{"a": 123}
```

I would like to parse it to same data type, **based on the `fopooo`, `baasdasda1`, etc** :

```hs
data Test
  = Foo
    { a :: Int
    , b :: Int
    }
  | Bar
    { a :: Int
    }
  deriving (Show, Generic)
```

In the Aeson there is a [tag feature](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-1.4.6.0/docs/Data-Aeson.html#v:constructorTagModifier), but it seems to require presence of the tag inside the object.

**Is there some way to handle it like (with tag outside)**

```hs
magicDecode :: String -> Test
magicDecode "fooooo" = decodeSpecyfic Foo
magicDecode "barrrr" = decodeSpecyfic Bar
```

Or something similar to it?

## edit1

I've currenlty mananged to handle types with records by this

```hs
test :: [(String, Text)]
test =
  [ ("foooo", "Foo")
  , ("barrr", "Bar")
  , ("aaaa", "Lel")
  ]

dec :: String -> ByteString -> Test
dec t x =
  fromJust $
  parseMaybe
    (genericParseJSON defaultOptions {sumEncoding = ObjectWithSingleField})
    (object [fromJust (lookup t test) .= fromJust (decode x :: Maybe Value)])
```

(Issue is if thee are no constructor params :( )

Comment: Is `data Test = Test { a :: Int, b :: Maybe Int }` out of the question?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `UntaggedValue` option:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}
module Q59916344 where

import Data.Aeson
import GHC.Generics

myOptions = defaultOptions { sumEncoding = UntaggedValue }

data Test = Foo { a :: Int, b :: Int } | Bar { a :: Int } deriving (Show, Generic)

instance FromJSON Test where
  parseJSON = genericParseJSON myOptions

instance ToJSON Test where
  toJSON     = genericToJSON myOptions
  toEncoding = genericToEncoding myOptions
```

As [the documentation](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson/docs/Data-Aeson.html) explains about `UntaggedValue`:

> When decoding, constructors are tried in the order of definition. If some encodings overlap, the first one defined will succeed.

Demo:

```
*Q59916344 Q59916344> decode "{\"a\": 123}" :: Maybe Test
Just (Bar {a = 123})
*Q59916344 Q59916344> decode "{\"a\": 123, \"b\": 123}" :: Maybe Test
Just (Foo {a = 123, b = 123})
```

That said, **you shouldn't model sum types with records**, because the record accessors are partial:

```
*Q59916344 Q59916344> b (Foo 42 1337)
1337
*Q59916344 Q59916344> b (Bar 42)
*** Exception: No match in record selector b
```

Comment: In your example there is nothing about which constructor to pick

Comment: @majkrzak As the documentation explains, that happens automatically. If you have run-time JSON values, how do you plan on selecting between the options at design time?

Comment: the cosntructor which have to be chosen is tererminated by the tag value

Comment: @majkrzak Which tag?

Comment: `fooooo` from the example for example

Comment: @majkrzak Oh, that's part of your input? It doesn't look like JSON, though, so it'll probably be better to write a general parser for it.

Comment: Genarlly input is pair of the strings: key and json. Will try to edit the questions to make it clear. Sorry

Comment: @majkrzak, it seems to me that you have two completely different decoders, which is decided by the tag. The fact that they decode to the same type is almost irrelevant. Maybe have your tag return a decoder: `magicDecode :: String -> Object -> Result Test`