# Get name of the constructor

Tags: haskell, generics, template-haskell

I'm trying to find a way to be able to get name of my datatype constructor as String

```hs
data Test
  = Foo
    { a :: Int
    , b :: Int
    }
  | Bar
    { a :: Int
    }
  | Lol
  | Lel String
```

I'm searching something in form of `name :: Constructor Test -> String` which can be used like:

```hs
name Lol -- "Lol"
name Foo -- "Foo"
name Lel -- "Lel"
```

Closest what I was able to achieve was:

```hs
module Main where

import Data.Typeable
import Data.Data

data Test
  = Foo
    { a :: Int
    , b :: Int
    }
  | Bar
    { a :: Int
    }
  | Lol
  | Lel String
  deriving (Show, Data, Typeable)


main :: IO ()
main = do
  print $ toConstr Lol
  print $ toConstr $ Bar undefined
  print $ toConstr $ Foo undefined undefined
```

but `toConstr` excepts object as a argument instead of the constructor :/

Comment: Is this question somehow related to [your question from a few days ago](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59916344/126014)? If so, it may be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/135815), and you might be better off asking a question closer to your actual problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that the constructors themselves have types:

```
Foo :: Int -> Int -> Test
Bar :: Int -> Test
Lol :: Test
Lel :: Strinng -> Test
```

so you're asking for a function `name` that can take a constructor whose type matches any one of these "patterns" to produce a `String`.  If you wrote down the type signature for `name`, it would need to look something like:

```
name :: (a1 -> a2 -> ... -> an -> Test) -> String
```

or, if we wanted to use it with any object, not just `Test`, something like:

```
name :: (a1 -> a2 -> ... -> an -> finalObject) -> String
```

where the number of `a` types depends on the arity of the constructor.

There's no straightforward way of writing such a function in Haskell.  In fact, it's impossible in "plain" Haskell.  However, with some extensions, it can be done using some type class trickery.

The extensions needed are:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveDataTypeable #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}
```

The idea is to introduce a type class for the `name` function:

```
class Name a where
    name :: a -> String
```

and then introduce an instance that handles the case where `a` still needs arguments by supplying `undefined` to reduce the argument count by one:

```
instance Name (r -> a) where
    name f = name (f undefined)
```

This instance will be used recursively.  When we call `name Foo`, it'll be used to reduce this to `name (Foo undefined)` and then used again to reduce it to `name (Foo undefined undefined)`.  Since this final object doesn't match the pattern `r -> a`, we'll be ready to use the default instance:

```
instance Name a where
    name = show . toConstr
```

This code won't work as-is.  We need to add some constraints in appropriate places and use an `OVERLAPPING` pragma to handle these overlapping instances, but the final definition of the type class and its instances is:

```
class Name a where
  name :: a -> String
instance {-# OVERLAPPING #-} Name a => Name (r -> a) where
  name f = name (f undefined)
instance (Data a) => Name a where
  name = show . toConstr
```

This works fine:

```
λ> name Foo
"Foo"
λ> name Bar
"Bar"
λ> name Lol
"Lol"
λ> name Lel
"Lel"
```

However, now that you *have* this function, I think you will discover that it's incredibly difficult to use in a real program.

Anyway, the full code follows.  Note that modern versions of GHC don't need `deriving Typeable`, so you can leave it out.

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveDataTypeable #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}

module Constructor where

import Data.Data

data Test
  = Foo
    { a :: Int
    , b :: Int
    }
  | Bar
    { a :: Int
    }
  | Lol
  | Lel String
  deriving (Show, Data)

class Name a where
  name :: a -> String
instance {-# OVERLAPPING #-} Name a => Name (r -> a) where
  name f = name (f undefined)
instance (Data a) => Name a where
  name = show . toConstr

main = do
  print $ name Foo
  print $ name Bar
  print $ name Lol
  print $ name Lel
```

Comment: It works well, I reasembled it over generics, but can not figure out why instances are overloaping

Comment: Note that constraints are checked *after* instances are matched and play no role in instance selection or determination of overlap.  So, the instances above overlap because `instance Name a` overlaps with every other possible instance, including `instance Name (r -> a)`.